# Is it possible to break media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

This is a bit of an odd question, and I know it goes completely against the purpose of media queries, but is it possible to show the CSS for a desktop on a mobile device without touching the CSS files?

Our website is fully responsive. However, I have had a request to add a button to the page only on mobile devices which, when clicked, will show the page in desktop view.  I have explained why this is a bad idea, and given alternative solutions, but this is what the client wants.

I have tried the following code (changing the initial scale), and this works just fine on a desktop browser, but doesn't work on a physical mobile device.

```
<div id="desktop-view-btn">
    <a class="btn">Desktop</a>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    #desktop-view-btn {
      display:none;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
      #desktop-view-btn {
        display:block;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#desktop-view-btn')
          .insertBefore('h1')
          .on('click', 'a', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content',"width=device-width, initial-scale=0");
              $(this).parent().remove();
          });
  });
  </script>
```

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: `width=device-width` in the viewport meta tag is the basis of making things responsive, but you don’t want responsive here … You should rather be setting this to a fixed width, don’t you think?

Comment: @CBroe Unfortunately, setting the device width has no effect, even in a desktop browser

Comment: I tested it in Chrome’s mobile emulation mode, and setting `width=1200` while emulating an iPhone, showed the desktop view in there fine. It might differ for actual mobile devices, though. And not sure whether all browsers/devices will let you dynamically manipulate this after page load, you might try and make a reound-trip to the server, and reload the page with such a width set initially.

Comment: Thanks.  You are right that it does work in the chrome emulator, but if you simply resize your browser window, it does not work. Likewise, it doesn't work on an actual mobile device, even after a round trip. Maybe this isn't possible?